# Elasticsearch - using nested query with must_not not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 user in index, each user have nested roles:

user ID=1

```
{
    "id": [1]
}
```

user ID=2

```
{
    "id": [1]
},
{
    "id": [2]
},
{
    "id": [3]
}
```

user ID=3

```
{
    "id": [2]
},
{
    "id": [3]
}
```

user ID=4

```
{
    "id": [3]
}
```

The first user with ID=1 have roles with ID=1
The second user with ID=2 have roles with ID=1,2,3
The third user with ID=3 have roles with ID=2,3
The fourth user with ID=4 have roles with ID=3

In first query I am trying to get all users who have role with ID=3 and that query is working:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "roles",
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {
                                                    "match": {
                                                        "roles.id": 3
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

the query works as expected, users with ID=2,3,4 are returned

but when I try to get all users which do not have role with ID=3 (must from previous query is changed to must_not) it is not working as I would expect, I would expect that only user with ID=1 will be returned because he has no role ID=3, instead of that users with ID=1,2,3 are returned:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "roles",
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must_not": [
                                                {
                                                    "match": {
                                                        "roles.id": 3
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Only users where that is only role must_not is working, for other users which have more roles it is not working as expected, does anyone know what should I change to get query which I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query. It's the same query but simplified one.

```
GET test_index_nested/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "roles",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "roles.id": 3
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The test data if you need:

```
PUT test_index_nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "roles": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test_index_nested/_doc/1?pretty
{
  "roles" : [
    {
      "id" : "1"
    },
    {
      "id" : "2"
    }
  ]
}

PUT test_index_nested/_doc/2?pretty
{
  "roles" : [
    {
      "id" : "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found proper query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": [
                            {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "roles",
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "should": [
                                                {
                                                    "match": {
                                                        "roles.id": 3
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

must_not should be before nested

Comment: Good job! Your query can be further simplified by the way, there are many useless nestings